# Pass value of list view to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, list

I have a list that is being created dynamically. Part of code that creates a list is:

```
<ul>
    <?
        foreach ($folders as $folder)
            {
                $folder = str_replace("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "", $folder);
                $folder2 = str_replace("[Gmail]/", "", $folder);
            ?>
                <li>
                    <a><div id="box"><? echo $folder2; ?> </div></a>
                </li>
            <?}
</ul>

<div id="maillist"></div>
```

o/p of $folder

```
GMAIL/All Mail
GMAIL/Drafts
GMAIL/Important
```

o/p of $folder2

```
All Mail
Drafts
Important
```

what i want is that when a user clicks on All Mail, value corresponding to it (in this case: GMAIL/All Mail) should get pass to another script through ajax. The same process should follow for the other values in list also

ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').change(function(){

        var boxid = $('#box').val();
        console.log($('#box'))
        if(boxid != 0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'a_fetchmaillist.php',
                data:{id:boxid},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#maillist').html(returndata);
                    console.log(returndata)
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Can anyone tell if its possible to do what i want and if yes then how will it be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **do not assign the same id multiple times**, instead, set a class (eg `box`).

Then assign a data attribute for the specific folder ( eg. `box-allMails` ) and select that attribute on change:

```
foreach ($folders as $folder)
{
   $folder = str_replace("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "", $folder);
   $folder2 = str_replace("[Gmail]/", "", $folder);
?>
   <li>
     <div class="box" data-folder="<? echo $folder2 ?>"><? echo $folder2; ?></div>
   </li>
<?}
```

Then on change:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function() {
   var folder = $(this).attr('data-folder');
   // ajax call..
});
```

**UPDATE**

**Important:** You have to listen to 'click' event instead of 'change' because you click on a div, not on an input (I've changed the code).

**Event delegation:** Take note at the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dynamic-element', function() { .. })
```

instead of:

```
$('.element').on('click', function() { .. });
```

**The second will not work** because you are creating the elements dynamically.

**Clickable**: You do not have to insert an anchor tag to make the list item clickable unless you want to redirect to another page. In your case, you can style the `.box` div in order to get a cursor-pointer like this:

CSS

```
.box { cursor:pointer }
```

jQuery will take care of the rest (Check the example)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box', function() {
  var folder = $(this).attr('data-folder');
  alert('You clicked on: ' + folder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><div class="box" data-folder="folderOne">Folder One</div></li>
  <li><div class="box" data-folder="folderTwo">Folder Two</div></li>
  <li><div class="box" data-folder="folderThree">Folder Three</div></li>
  <li><div class="box" data-folder="folderFour">Folder Four</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first point is that i introduced an anchor tag, to make the list item clickable(not sure how well it will work, would appreciate if u could look at it), second point , i tried your code and did a console.log to check value of var folder but didn't got anything in it, am i missing somethin?